# creating onset variable for wide data

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have clinical data that records a patient at four_time points with a disease outcome indicated by a binary variable for each time point. It looks something like this

```
patientid <- c(100,101,102)
outcome_t1 <- c(1,1,1)
outcome_t2 <- c(0,1,1) 
outcome_t3 <- c(0,0,1)
outcome_t4 <- c(0,0,0)

Data<- data.frame(patientid=patientid,outcome_t1=outcome_t1, outcome_t2=outcome_t2, outcome_t3=outcome_t3, outcome_t4=outcome_t4)
Data
```

I want to create an onset variable. The onset variable should indicate if a patient experienced disease onset anytime between time point 1 and 4. The caveat is that if the patient had the disease at time point point (outcome_t1), then this does not count as onset and thus onset = 0. I need code to create the onset variable. Once completed the data should look like this:

```
patientid <- c(100,101,102)
outcome_t1 <- c(1,1,1)
outcome_t2 <- c(0,1,1) 
outcome_t3 <- c(0,0,1)
outcome_t4 <- c(0,0,0)
onset <- c(0,1,1)

Data<- data.frame(patientid=patientid,outcome_t1=outcome_t1, outcome_t2=outcome_t2, outcome_t3=outcome_t3, outcome_t4=outcome_t4, onset = onset)
Data
```

Therefore I would like some code/ some help automating the creation of the onset variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for. I assumed only `outcome_t2` and `outcome_t3` are considered for your `onset` variable but if that's not the case it can be easily fixed.

```
library(dplyr)

Data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(onset = ifelse(any(c_across(outcome_t2:outcome_t3) == 1), 
                        1, 0))

# A tibble: 3 x 6
# Rowwise: 
  patientid outcome_t1 outcome_t2 outcome_t3 outcome_t4 onset
      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
1       100          1          0          0          0     0
2       101          1          1          0          0     1
3       102          1          1          1          0     1
```

Answer (score 1):

We `select` the columns of interest and apply `rowSums` on logical matrix, convert the count to a logical vector and coerce it to binary (`+`)

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% 
 mutate(onset = +(rowSums(select(., matches('outcome_t[2-3]')) == 1) > 0))
```

-output

```
#    patientid outcome_t1 outcome_t2 outcome_t3 outcome_t4 onset
#1       100          1          0          0          0     0
#2       101          1          1          0          0     1
#3       102          1          1          1          0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's maybe a mistake in the data setup you provided (all the cases have 1 for outcome_t1 but onset has 1s). Assuming that's the case, does this work? The answer by @Anoushiravan does not account for 1s in the outcome_t1 field.

```
library(dplyr)

Data <- Data %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(Onset = ifelse(sum(c(outcome_t1, outcome_t2, outcome_t3, outcome_t4)) > 0 & outcome_t1 ==0, 1, 0))
```